# How much ram can I use with 2CPUs

Tags: memory, proxmox

I have a question about a new server that I want to buy. This server has 2CPUs and 32gb of ram in total. My question is: can I use all the 32gb of ram for proxmox, and therefore for the vm, or can I use only 16gb?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use 30GB of RAM out of 32GB, and leave 1-2GB of host RAM, for iptables, fail2ban, etc. and add some **SWAP RAM** on top. Same if you choose the 16GB server: 14GB for guests, 2GB for host.

Assuming you're referring to **Proxmox** to manage guest virtual machines, you can give it as much RAM as you want.

But, the *very first thing* I would do is submit a ticket to the cloud/ISP you're using and ask them if the server you want has **nested virtualization**.

If the server has KVM and allows "nested virtualization", you'll be fine. If not, it will struggle with more than 1 guest VM.

If the answer is **yes** to "nested virtualization", then you can use unlimited RAM really, and QEMU will do what it's told because all the guests will share the 2 CPUs.

If the answer is **no** to "nested virtualization", then the 2 CPUs with 32GB is most likely 2x vCPUs, and its going to struggle.

From experience, I doubt 2 CPUs with 32GB of ram will have "nested virt.".

You can check when you're in the server:

Enable KVM first.

```sh
sudo modprobe kvm
```

See if KVM works:

```sh
stat /dev/kvm
```

```
stat /dev/kvm
#  File: /dev/kvm
#  Size: 0          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special #file
#Device: 0,5    Inode: 780         Links: 1     Device type: 10,232
#Access: (0666/crw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   78/     kvm)
#Access: 2022-01-29 11:26:05.478771780 +0000
#Modify: 2022-01-29 11:26:05.478771780 +0000
#Change: 2022-01-29 11:26:05.478771780 +0000
# Birth: -
```

If you get `stat: cannot statx '/dev/kvm: No such file or directory` then the server will struggle, and you will most likely want a refund on that server.

You can check the CPU info too:

```sh
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Here's a virtual CPU with no nested virtualization

```
[root@hostname ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Virtual CPU 82d9ed4018dd
```

Here's a normal CPU with virtualization

```
[user@hostname ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 96
model name  : AMD Ryzen 9 4900H with Radeon Graphics
```

Then you can watch the RAM as you use the server.

```
# see all RAM usage
free -mh
```

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation, but is not the answer for my question.... maybe i was not clear. I want to buy a physic server and it has 2CPUs(X5650) and 32gb of ram split between the 2CPUs(16gb on the first and 16gb on the second). My question was: Can i use all the 32gb of my server or only 16gb because the ram is split?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you means 2 CPU's, like 2 CPU cores, as most clouds present their offerings. It sounds like you're purchasing 2 X5650's, so that would be 6 cores on each, so 12 cores, with 24 threads between the two systems? I am unaware of being able to "aggregate" two servers. Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, a server with 2 sockets and so 2CPUs (dell r710)